# Достать название картинки из второй таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы: `s_products` и `s_images`

В `s_products` содержится информация о товаре и его `id`; 
 
В `s_images` содержится информация об изображении к товару.
 Они соотносятся по `id`, (`s_products` - `id`, `s_images` - `product_id`).

Как мне в одном цикле вытащить информацию о продукте из `s_products`, с условием `WHERE visible = 1`, и название картинки(в бд `s_images` столбец названия - `filename`) для вывода картинки непосредственно на страницу?

Пытался вытащить вот так, ничего не вышло:

```
 $qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT s_products.*, s_images.*
         FROM s_products, s_images WHERE s_products.id=s_images.product_id")
              or die(mysql_error());
 While($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
    echo $data['name'];
    echo $data['filename'];
    }
```

Так не срабатывает.

Comment: select p.*, i.filename from s_products as p inner join s_images as i on p.id = i.product_id where p.visible = 1; может так попробовать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнить таким образом:

```
 $qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT name, filename
             FROM s_products, s_images WHERE id = product_id AND visible = 1")
              or die(mysql_error());
 While($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
    echo $data['name'];
    echo $data['filename'];
    }
```